Why do I get "TypeError: simpleContract.deployed is not a function at main" when deploying a contract?
In contracts/SimpleContract.sol:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract SimpleContract {
    string public message = "Hello, World!";
}

In scripts/deploy.js
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  console.log("Deploying SimpleContract...");

  const SimpleContract = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("SimpleContract");
  const simpleContract = await SimpleContract.deploy();

  console.log("Contract deployment transaction created, waiting for      confirmation...");
  await simpleContract.deployed();

  console.log("SimpleContract deployed to:", simpleContract.address);
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error("Error during deployment:", error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});

I try to deploy this and get this error:
C:\ProgStuff\solidity-check>npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost
Deploying SimpleContract...
Contract deployment transaction created, waiting for confirmation...
Error during deployment: TypeError: simpleContract.deployed is not a function
    at main (C:\ProgStuff\solidity-check\scripts\deploy.js:29:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Why am I getting this error and how can I solve it?

You have used old version of deploy script and solidity.
Some functions are deprecated.
You should write as follows:
import { ethers } from 'hardhat'

async function main() {
  console.log("Deploying SimpleContract...");
  
  const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
  const simpleContract = await ethers.deployContract("SimpleContract");
  
  console.log("Contract deployment transaction created, waiting for confirmation...");
  await simpleContract.waitForDeployment();
  
  const contractAddress = await simpleContract.getAddress();
  console.log("SimpleContract deployed to:", contractAddress);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch(error => {
    console.error("Error during deployment:", error)
    process.exitCode = 1
  })

